# Exposing metrics about current Websocket connections with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics, spring-websocket

For my dashboarding application I want to monitor my Spring Boot based application with internal Spring metrics. Therefor I am using the `spring-boot-actuator` dependency which is exposing a lot of internal metrics. There are a lot of HTTP based metrics and Tomcat metrics like current sessions, amount of HTTP calls of status X and so on. I coulnd't find any information regarding my Websocket connections.

Is there any build-in out of the box metrics exposing tool for the current Websockets with Spring or do I have to create my own metrics (e.g. for showing the data in Grafana with Prometheus) and have to manually register for example a counter which is updated when I receive a `SessionConnectEvent` or `SessionConnectEvent`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using STOMP over WebSocket, Spring aggregates information about internal state and counters from key infrastructure components of the setup in `WebSocketMessageBrokerStats`, by default this is logged every 30 seconds. It is created as a Spring bean and can be easily autowired. This is an example of the information you'll get: [image: WebSocketMessageBrokerStats output]

There are no actuator endpoints currently, but I've created them as part of my [Spring WebSocket Chat](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat) sample:

- [Trace Endpoint](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/trace/websocket/WebSocketTraceEndpoint.java): exposes WebSocket traces
- [Mappings Endpoint](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/MessageMappingEndpoint.java): exposes WebSocket message mappings
- [Stats Endpoint](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/WebSocketStatsEndpoint.java): exposes WebSocketMessageBrokerStats

Answer (score 5):

Found very easy way.

If you are using STOMP over WebSocket, in your controller class just autowire WebSocketMessageBrokerStats class and use it's methods.

```
@Autowired
WebSocketMessageBrokerStats webSocketMessageBrokerStats;

System.out.println("Session Stats info " +webSocketMessageBrokerStats.getWebSocketSessionStatsInfo());
```

No need of creating any separate class.

Read https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-stats for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Also, there is one more way. If you want to get more details about active sessions then it contains in `SubProtocolWebSocketHandler`. This bean handles active session and has a method `getStats`. Stats object has methods:

```
        int getTotalSessions();

        int getWebSocketSessions();

        int getHttpStreamingSessions();

        int getHttpPollingSessions();

        int getLimitExceededSessions();

        int getNoMessagesReceivedSessions();

        int getTransportErrorSessions();
```

Actually `WebSocketMessageBrokerStats` uses method `#SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.getStatsInfo` which invokes `toSting` on Stats object.

So, possible code will look like:

```
  @Autowired
  private WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler;

  @GetMapping("/total")
  public int getTotalSessions() {
    return ((SubProtocolWebSocketHandler) webSocketHandler).getStats().getTotalSessions();
  }
```