# StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - Transport failure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No TcpConnection available

Tags: java, websocket, stomp, spring-messaging

We use STOMP broker relay(External Broker - ActiveMQ 5.13.2) in our Project see
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-handle-broker-relay

We use following stack:

```
org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE
io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE
io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:0.8.6.RELEASE
io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.34.Final
```

From time to time(lets say once a 2 weeks) we can observe in tomcat catalina.out logs error

```
2019-08-21 13:38:58,891 [tcp-client-scheduler-5] ERROR com.*.websocket.stomp.SimpMessagingSender  - BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=false, StompBrokerRelay[ReactorNettyTcpClient[reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientDoOn@219abb46]]]
2019-08-21 13:38:58,965 [tcp-client-scheduler-1] ERROR org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler  - Transport failure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No TcpConnection available
```

After that error STOMP communication is broken(`system` connection - single TCP connection is not available)

And it seems that everything started when we update stack from:

```
org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE
io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.1.8.RELEASE
io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:0.7.8.RELEASE
io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.25.Final
```

ActiveMQ version not changed

There is a bug reported in spring that auto-reconnect failed when the `system` connection lost see:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22080

And now 3 questions:

1. How to make this problem more reproducible?
2. How to fix this reconnect behavior? :)
3. How to prevent to lose this connection? :)

**EDIT 23.09.2019**

After error occurred TCP stack for port 61613(STOMP) is the following(Please note CLOSE_WAIT state):

```
netstat -an | grep 61613
tcp6       0      0 :::61613                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       2      0 127.0.0.1:49084         127.0.0.1:61613         CLOSE_WAIT
```

Comment: While ActiveMQ is involved here it doesn't appear to be the source of the issue (especially given the fact that the version hasn't changed) so I'm removing the `activemq` tag.

Comment: Just an idea, but does this occur after the main router goes offline and comes back up? I have some software that seem to need to restart their services when the network goes down an comes back up.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I have enough information to answer your question although I have some input that may help you find a way forward.

ActiveMQ is typically used in an environment that is hosted/distributed, so load and scaling should always be a consideration.

Most dbs/message queues/ect.. will need some sort of tuning for load - even on AWS (via requesting higher limits) even though most of that is taken care of by the hosting provider.

But I digress...

In this case it appears you're using the TCP transport for your queue:

https://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference

As you can see, all of these settings can be tuned and have default values.

So in the case of issues logged from the *spring side* connecting to AMQ, you'll want to narrow down the time of the error and then go look at your AMQ metrics and logs.

If you don't have monitoring for AMQ, I suggest:

1. Add Monitoring - https://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-monitor-activemq
2. Add logging (or find out where the logs are). - Then enable detailed logging. (AMQ uses log4j, so just look at the log4j config file or add one.) Beyond this, consider sending the logs to a log aggregator. -- https://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-enable-detailed-logging
3. Look at your hosting provider's metrics & downtime. For instance, if using AWS, there are very detailed incident logs for network failures or momentary issues with VPC or cross-region tunneling, network traffic in/out ect..

Setting up the right tools for your distributed systems to enable your team to search/find errors/logs (and documenting how to do it) is extremely helpful. A step beyond this (for mature systems) is to add a layer on top of your monitoring so that your systems start telling you when there is a problem instead of the other way around (go looking for problems).

That may be a bit verbose - but that all leads up to me asking if you have logs / metrics for the AMQ system at the times of the failure. If you do, please post them!

I make these suggestions because:

- There is no information provided on your load expectation, variability of load, or recognition that load is a consideration in a system (via troubleshooting steps).
- Logs/errors provided are strictly from the client side.
- The reproducibility of the error is infrequent and inconsistent - so it could be almost anything (memory leak, load issue, etc..) - so monitoring is necessary.

Also consider adding Spring Actuator for monitoring your message client on the spring side, as there are frequently limitations/settings for client connection pools & advanced settings too, especially if you scale up/down instance size, etc.. and your instance will be handling more/less load, your client libs may need some settings tuning.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators

[Exposing metrics about current Websocket connections with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687540/exposing-metrics-about-current-websocket-connections-with-spring)

You can also catch the exception and tear down & re-create your connection/settings - although this wouldn't be the first thing I recommend without knowing more about the situations & stats at the time of the connection failure.

Comment: Despite the fact that this answer does not resolve the problem, you earn points, in recognition of the attempt.